# Mongo aggregate query pulling out last 7 days worth of data (node.js)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a large collection of data which I'm trying to pull out of Mongo (node js) in order to render some graphs.

I need to pull the last 7 days worth of data out of a few thousand users. The specific piece of data on each user is formatted like so:

```
{
    "passedModules" : 
    [{
        "module" : ObjectId("53ea17dcac1d13a66fb6d14e"),
        "date" : ISODate("2014-09-17T00:00:00.000Z")
    }, 
    {
        "module" : ObjectId("53ec5c91af2792f1112554e8"),
        "date" : ISODate("2014-09-17T00:00:00.000Z")
    }, 
    {
        "module" : ObjectId("53ec5c5baf2792f1112554e6"),
        "date" : ISODate("2014-09-17T00:00:00.000Z")
    }]
}
```

At the moment I have a really messy group of queries which is working, but I believe this is possible to do entirely with Mongo?

Basically, I need to pull out all the entries from 7 days ago until now, in a dynamic fashion.

Is there a tried and testing way of working with dynamic dates in this way, more specifically using the aggregation framework in mongo? The reason for the aggregation framework is that I need to group these afterwards.

Many thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general pattern for this type of query is:

```
// Compute the time 7 days ago to use in filtering the data
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate()-7);

db.users.aggregate([
    // Only include the docs that have at least one passedModules element
    // that passes the filter.
    {$match: {'passedModules.date': {$gt: d}}},
    // Duplicate the docs, one per passedModules element
    {$unwind: '$passedModules'},
    // Filter again to remove the non-matching elements
    {$match: {'passedModules.date': {$gt: d}}}
])
```

Answer (score 2):

@JohnnyHK has a good answer already. But if you are using a querying tool (Like Robot3T or Metabase) and don't have programmatic access to create and change variables, here's another option.

```json
    {
        "$match": {
            "$expr":{
                "$gte":[
                    "$passedModules.date",
                    { $add: [new Date(), -604800000]}
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

Where the number `604800000` is just the time in milliseconds: `1000*60*60*24*<Number of Days>`

You can make it relative to the week or month as well.

```json
    {
        
        "$match": {
            "$expr":{
                "$eq":[
                    { $add:[ {$multiply:[1000, { $year: ["$passedModules.date"] }]}, { $week: ["$passedModules.date"] } ]},
                    { $add:[ {$multiply:[1000, { $year: [new Date()] }]}, { $week: [new Date()] } ]}
                ]
            }
        }
    },
```

Hope it can help others in the same context as I was.